# How to broadcast this array with Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

In this Python 3.11 code snippet:

```
import numpy as np

state = np.arange(48, dtype='u1').reshape((2, 8, 3))
pixels = [3, 4, 5]
colors = [[42, 43, 44], [0, 1, 2]]
state[0, pixels] = colors[0]  # line 1
state[1, pixels] = colors[1]  # line 2
# state[:, pixels, :] = colors  # error
```

I would like to replace `line 1` and `line 2` with a single line Numpy magic. The last line doesn't compile.

Comment: what is the actual error?

Comment: @hpaulj ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (2,3) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (2,3,3)

Comment: the lines that work put a (3,) into a (2,3).  (3,) expands to (1,3) and then (2,3).  Together `colors` needs to be (2,1,3) or (2,3,1) to go into (2,3,3)

Comment: oops, the working ones have a (3,3) lhs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`colors` need to have the same number of dimensions as `state`

```
state = np.arange(48, dtype='u1').reshape((2, 8, 3))
pixels = [3, 4, 5]
colors = np.array([[42, 43, 44], [0, 1, 2]])
state[:,pixels,:] = np.expand_dims(colors, axis=1)
print(state)
```

Output

```
[[[ 0  1  2]
  [ 3  4  5]
  [ 6  7  8]
  [42 43 44]
  [42 43 44]
  [42 43 44]
  [18 19 20]
  [21 22 23]]

 [[24 25 26]
  [27 28 29]
  [30 31 32]
  [ 0  1  2]
  [ 0  1  2]
  [ 0  1  2]
  [42 43 44]
  [45 46 47]]]
```

Comment: It produces a different result than my example. I'm expecting: [[[ 0  1  2]
  [ 3  4  5]
  [ 6  7  8]
  [42 43 44]
  [42 43 44]
  [42 43 44]
  [18 19 20]
  [21 22 23]]

 [[24 25 26]
  [27 28 29]
  [30 31 32]
  [ 0  1  2]
  [ 0  1  2]
  [ 0  1  2]
  [42 43 44]
  [45 46 47]]]